# How can I do large file in-memory processing in Python?

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a series of files that are 80 GB compressed .bz files.  I have to take these files, make them into JSON objects, and compress and export them into tar.gz compressed files split into 500 MB blocks.

```
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import bz2
import time

start_time = time.time()

os.system("kinit svc-cypressadm@1DC.COM -k -t  /hadoop/svc-cypressadm/svc-cypressadm.keytab")

now = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=2)

day = now.strftime("%d")
month = now.strftime("%m")
year = now.strftime("%Y") 

os.system("hadoop fs -copyToLocal /data/SOUTH.bz2 south.bz2")

bz_file = bz2.BZ2File("south.bz2")

print "Test Point 1A"

os.system("mkfifo gzip_pipe")

print "Test Point 1B"

os.system("gzip -9 -c gzip_pipe >> fast_south.gz")

print "Test Point 1C"

os.system("exec 3>> gzip_pipe")

print "Test Point 1D"

dataJSON = {}

writingFile = open("south.json", "w")

i = 0

print "Test Point 1E"

for line in bz_file:


    #dataJSON = {}

    line = unicode(line, "ISO-8859-1")

    dataJSON["authu_rec_type"] = line[0:0] 
    dataJSON["authu_avs_code"] = line[1:1]
    dataJSON["authu_acct_numb"] = line[2:18]
    dataJSON["authu_date"] = line[19:23]

    ... (More fields here)

    json_data = json.dumps(dataJSON)

    json_data = json_data + "\n"

    #json_data = "\"" + json_data + "\""

    i = i + 1

    #writingFile = open("south.json", "w")

    writingFile.write(json_data)

    if i == 1000:

        print "Test Point 2A"

        commandLineString = "cat south.json >> 3"

        #writingFile.close()

        os.system(commandLineString)

        print "Test Point 2B"

        os.system("rm south_credit_debit_auth_20100731.json")        

        print str(i) + ": " + commandLineString

        writingFile = open("south.json", "w")

        i = 0



#commandString = "tar -cvzf south.tar.gz south.json"

#system.os(commandString)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I need to do this in memory as I need to do it as quickly as possible.

Comment: the .gz files are 80gig, or it's 80gig of raw data that's been compressed down into (hopefully smaller) .gz files?

Comment: This sounds like it would be done much faster using a service like: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/

Comment: 80 gb .bz files.  Uncompressed 10:1 can be 800 gb.  @MarcB

Comment: how big is your RAM? Is it several GB higher than 80 GB? No? Then you can't. Yes? Then it should be possible assuming you keep the overhead from your programme low.

Comment: @SonOfSeuss, is your RAM higher than 800GB?

Comment: if your dataJSON is a simple dict, can't you easily build a valid JSON stream?

Comment: sorry. I didn't read your code completely. It appears that you are already processing the large input file line by line, and each JSON obj only represents a line. I'm surprised you are running into memory issues.

Comment: Have a look at Apache Spark.